# Page splitting into two columns suddenly after \includegraphics

Tags: two-column, wrapfigure, includegraphics

I am using the following wrapfigure

```
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.59\textwidth}
        \vspace*{-25mm}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=10cm, height=10cm]{figures/spatialcoherence.png}
        \vspace*{-6mm}
        \caption{Spatial coherence method.}
    \end{wrapfigure}
```

and `\includegraphics` line inside that makes all the subsequent pages split into two columns(see the image below).
[image]

If I omit or comment out the `\includegraphics` the page becomes single column again(image below).

[image]

Any idea how and why is this happening?

the packages I am using are:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{bm} % bold math symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}  %package to manage images
\graphicspath{{./figures/}} % folder where the images or figures are
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % make Figure 1 bold
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapping a figure with words
\usepackage{hyperref} % for hyperlinks, citations
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Peptide_analysis},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document} ...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With the code you provided, it is not possible to reproduce the problem you have. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: possibly unrelated but usualy better to use height or width not both `width=10cm, height=10cm` is `0.59\textwidth` bigger than 10cm ?

Comment: includegraphics itself will not affect this but without it the wrapfig is 10cm shorter so obviously all line breaking is different

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't confirm your claims. Composing MWE from your code fragments gives expected result. BTW, due to `\vspace*{-25mm}` image is moved above paragraph and overlay over previous one.